# Searching amongst a list of strings

Tags: java, algorithm, string, text, java-me

I have a list of article names which are strings, and based on a user query, I need to output a best search out of that list of article names. I was thinking about what kind of an algorithm would work here. It should suggest the closest match possible, IMO. Or is there a better way of doing I have in mind?

Comment: don't reinvent the wheel, if your data is huge, and you expect a lot of queries, use Lucene to index these titles, and then just search (again, using Lucene) each query in the index.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using an *[edit distance](http://www.google.pt/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance&rct=j&q=edit%20distance&ei=wQX9TdOJIY278gPZib2qCQ&usg=AFQjCNGKDsyOhmvoi2Ojtaby4bXcemOeFA&cad=rja)* algorithm with a tolerance value of *n* (either in absolute or in percentage) for a result to be within the scope of the search-for example, an article whose edit distance to the query is more than 50% its length may be put out of scope in most cases. Next, you can sort results by their percentual edit distance to the query string so that an exact match is a 100% match, an article whose name is 99% similar to the query is ranked as 99% similar, and so on.

Comment: At the same time, can this be thought of as a Longest Common Subsequence problem?

Comment: No, it is not. In a "longest common subsequence" problem you take the query and search for an exact match of part of it in the article names. In an "edit distance" problem you find out how many additions, insertions and deletions of characters are needed to transform your query string into any of the articles.

Comment: Hmm, sure. Edit distance makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Lucine. This is a popular open source solution for text search. It will probably save your time preventing you from reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I have tagged java-me in the question, and AFAIK you cannot run Lucene on it.

Comment: @Gooner Even if you can't run Lucene on java-me, take a look at it anyway.  Read about it.  The techniques it employs aren't very hard to implement yourself, and seem right up to tackling your task.  If you can't use Lucene from java-me, then reinventing this wheel might be the thing to do